# Will ajax click function work in submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am doing a front-end of a site, and I need to display a popup modal the same time as submitting the form. I need to use INPUT TYPE="button" and I used JQUERY CLICK function instead of SUBMIT. Will the ajax in this code work and submit the form?

```js
$("#submit_cc").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "#",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'acctNumber': $('#acctNumber').val()
            }
        });modal.style.display = "block";
    });
/* Display popup modal */
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
//var btn = document.getElementById("submit_cc");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("span_cc_btn")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
/*btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}*/

// When the user clicks on <span>, close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    
    padding-top: 100px;
    /* Location of the box */
    
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    
    overflow: auto;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    color: #afafaf;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 30px;
}
.modal-content button {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
    background-color: #ea6a1d;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {
        top: -300px;
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1
    }
}
@keyframes animatetop {
    from {
        top: -300px;
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm_payt_cc">
 <h2>Payment</h2>

 <label class="bill_label">Account Number</label>

 <p><input type="number" name="acctNumber" class="form-control bill_value col-sm-12 col-xs-12" placeholder="Enter acct num"></p>
 
 <br><input type="button" id="submit_cc" class="bill_btn col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" value="Submit Payment &rarr;">
</form>

<!--  MODAL POP UP -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <!-- Modal content -->
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="bill_popup modal-body">
   <h2>Thank You!</h2>
   <br>
   <center><span class="span_cc_btn"><button type="button">Okay</button></span></center>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Will the ajax in this code work and submit the form?"* - What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It'll work, but it's not good practice.

Comment: @nnnnnn I just work on front end and I cant deal with back-end issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can definitely post all content of form using `POST` method in `ajax`, and thus you do not need to submit form, without submit you can post data to php using ajax.

small example is:

```
 $("#submit_cc").click(function(event){
    var $form = $("#testform"),
    url = $form.attr( 'action' );
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $form.serialize()
    });
 });
```

Comment: so `$("#button").click(function() {...` should work? Because in ajax examples, I see `.submit(function(){...` instead.

Comment: thanks. Will it still display the modal box I put after it submits?

Comment: if you want to display model after submit, put it inside button click event'

Comment: I am just beginning to learn AJAX. This will work now, right? Submit my form and display the modal: 

`$("#myButton").click(function() {
        var $form = $("#myForm"),
        url = $form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: $form.serialize()
        });
        modal.style.display = "block";
    });`

Comment: yes but declare model before click event. means put var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); before click event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117995/discussion-between-ladiesman1792-and-jayesh-chitroda).